# Android start activity

Tags: c#, android-intent, static, monodevelop, start-activity

I am using MonoDevelop for Android with the MapsAndlocationDemo and I have a question about starting another activity.

Here is my code:

```
    public void loadActivity (Context ActivityContext)
    {
        var second = new Intent(ActivityContext, typeof(LocationDetailsActivity));
        second.PutExtra("FirstData", "Data from FirstActivity");
        StartActivity (second);
    }
```

This code works perfectly when called from the `MapWithOverlayActivity : MapActivity` class. I am wanting to call it from the `MapItemizedOverlay: ItemizedOverlay` class when the `OnTap` method of a map marker is called.

I have tried to make the method static. Here is my code for this:

```
    static public void loadActivity (Context ActivityContext)
    {
        var second = new Intent(ActivityContext, typeof(LocationDetailsActivity));
        second.PutExtra("FirstData", "Data from FirstActivity");
        StartActivity (second);
    }
```

However, I now get the following error: `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property Android.Content.Context.StartActivity(Android.Content.Intent)`

Can I please have some information as to why this does not work, and some help to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Android's global Application object if it helps. Here's an example:

```
public class MyApp extends Application{
    private String foo = null;

    public String getFoo(){
        return foo;
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private MyApp app;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        app = ((MyApp)getApplication());

        String thing = app.getFoo();
    }
}
```

If you need the method to be accessible from anywhere you can replace the getFoo method with your Intent :) I think it should work. Application reference is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)

Comment: Thanks for your information. If possible, can you explain to me what the error means in my question? And also how to get it working.

Comment: What is the 'object reference' that is required?

Comment: Have you tried MapItemizedOverlay.this.loadActivity? I'm not completely sure

Comment: How do you call the static method?